# Prove that $a=b$ : An integral equality .

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

It's a problem I found nice and a little bit difficult so :

> Let :
>   $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\Big)^{\alpha\cos^2(x)}-\Big(x\Big)^{\alpha\sin^2(x)}}dx=a+ib$$
>   Then prove that :
>   $$a=b$$
>   Where $\alpha>0$ is a real number .

Clearly I don't know how to attack this problem .

I just know that :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\Big)^{\alpha\cos^2(x)}-\Big(x\Big)^{\alpha\sin^2(x)}dx=0$$

After that I want to apply [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)'s inequality (for integral) But I got nothing .

So have you a way to prove this ?

Thanks a lot for your time .

Comment: according to inequality, it seems that integral is equal to zero